# Deriving expected value and variance from given expected value and variance

Tags: statistics, variance, means

I am given E[3Z + 10] = 4, and Var[3Z + 10] = 36. How would I go about solving for the mean and variance of Z? I assume its not as simple as subtracting and dividing to solve for Z with either case...I also realize "3Z + 10" is included with both sides, which might be a give away to simplify but I am still unsure. Thank you.

Comment: The expected value operator is linear, so it is that simple. The variance operator is not linear, but it’s not much harder. Does your book state the properties?

Comment: @Joe, I didn't think I could have negative values for E[Z]! Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome. You might have been thinking about the variance, which is always nonnegative since it is $\operatorname{E} \left[ \left( Z - \operatorname{E} \left[ Z \right] \right)^2 \right]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: $E(3Z+10)=3EZ+10$ and $var(3Z+10)=var (3Z)=3^{2}var(Z)$.